# parameters for crystal reports with fox pro database

Tags: crystal-reports, foxpro

now i have connected my crystal report to my foxpro 6 database, i would now like to pass a parameter to a certain field so that i could filter the result of my report.

i do not have any code in crystal report yet, i do not have any code in visual foxpro also.

do you have any solutions regarding this matter?

i do think this is simple to other users, kindly share any insights and i will reply as quickly as i could because i really need this report.

i cant upload the picture to illustrate my problem, but i do really wish someone could help me out.

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial to use crystal reports with VFP http://www.craigberntson.com/docs/usingcr.pdf

Comment: how can i pass parameters in my report?

Comment: give a look @ his code http://computer-programming-forum.com/2-vfp/2f14785a2e3c401e.htm